Millisecond level chart refresh scheme
I need to use the browser to render the line chart data, there are 24 lines in total, and the data is pushed at a rate of 1ms. Each line needs to hold 10,000 data at most. I have tried to use open source libraries such as Echartjs and Chartjs, but they will cause congestion when there is too much data, is there any good solution?
I used Echart to configure it, although Echart is optimized for displaying a large amount of data, but when the data is updated, he takes a lot of time to compare, causing page congestion, I would like to discuss the solution to this problem
